# NoClassDefFoundError for Jar library

Tags: java, rdf, sesame

I am using Sesame to access a sample RDF repository,

```
String sesameServer = "http://asimov.ludat.lth.se/openrdf-sesame/";
String repositoryID = "KnowRob";
// Cannot create HTTPRepository
Repository myRepository = new HTTPRepository(sesameServer,repositoryID);
myRepository.initialize();
RepositoryConnection con = myRepository.getConnection();
```

however, I get a NoClassDefFoundError while trying to run the code above.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/httpclient/Credentials
    at org.openrdf.repository.http.HTTPRepository.<init>(HTTPRepository.java:54)
    at org.openrdf.repository.http.HTTPRepository.<init>(HTTPRepository.java:59)
    at RDF.Start.main(Start.java:30)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.httpclient.Credentials
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 3 more
```

Comment: Looks like you need [`Apache HttpClient`](http://hc.apache.org/) library in your classpath as well. Note that version 3.x and 4.x differs greatly, so be sure to find the right one for this project, that must be said in the README or somewhere else in the Sesame library.

Comment: I'd consider using Maven or an equivalent to handle your transitive dependency management; problems like this aren't worth dealing with manually.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Thanks! It wasn't exactly the problem, but I downloaded the `openrdf-sesame-2.6.10-sdk` instead of `openrdf-sesame-2.6.10-onejar` file from Sesame website, and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

NoClassDefFoundError exception occurs when used class not find in user-define class and defined classpath external jar.

So [download and configure classpath commons-httpclient-3.0.1.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcommonshttpclient301jar.htm) library in your classpath.

Comment: Your first sentence has really awkward grammar, and I'm not entirely sure what you were trying to say, or I would have edited it. Can you [edit] to clarify?